# Change datatype to be integer instead of string in JSON / Python print output

Tags: python, json, api

In general, I need the ID to come out as an integer and not a string. I am sure there is a super easy way to do this!

Have tried to loop the code but then I end up with hard brackets which our API won't recognize.

```
import csv
import json
import requests
import itertools
from collections import OrderedDict



json_dict = {}

results = []
with open('activity_test.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(f):
        results.append(row)

json_dict["activity"] = results                             

json_data = print(json.dumps(json_dict,indent=4))
```

This is the result (but I need the ID to not be in quotes aka not a string):

```
    {"activity": [
        {
            "id": "186405",
            "advertiser": "Disney Home Entertainment"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You could try opening the CSV with pandas and using the DF.to_json() function.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Comment: Please show content of your CSV file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the string to int:

```
json_dict = {}

results = []
with open('activity_test.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(f):
        row['id'] = int(row['id'])
        results.append(row)

json_dict["activity"] = results
```

If you are not sure of the format of your data, you can catch the exceptions.

Comment: THANK YOU! any chance you know how to drop the hard brackets completely? I just need 2 sets of curly brackets. right now the output is: 
{
    "activity": [
        {
            "id": 186405,
            "advertiser": "Disney Home Entertainment"
        }
    ]
}